# How to link a string in python code to a label in the kivy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, user-interface, kivy

I'll try to be as curt and straight to the point as possible, as I believe this is probably a simple solution.

How do I get a string that is defined in a python file to show up as a label within a kivy file? Below is a very basic idea on how I tried to achieve this.

kivy-tests.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Entry(BoxLayout):
    x = ObjectProperty('Trees')
        
class kvfiletests(App):
    def build(self):
        return Entry()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    kvfiletests().run()
```

kivyfiletests.kv

```
<Entry>
    x: set_name

    Label:
        id: set_name
        text: set_name.text
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The core part of the answer is that you need to set the Label's text to the text you want, but it looks like you've understood that so I'm not sure where the issue is. The id part isn't doing anything useful though, perhaps you mean `text: root.x`?

Comment: @inclement I removed the id and changed the value to ```text: root.x ```, and the only difference is that I get a ```KeyError: '' ```.

Comment: @inclement I figured it out to a certain degree. You were right. The only issue is that setting the variable name that I was using  as ```x``` was causing an issue, so I just changed that name and didn't have any further issues. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Working code - Only took 3 hours to figure this out!

Name your file as kivy-tests.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Entry(BoxLayout):
    urs = StringProperty('Custom text for Label/Button/TextInput')
    
class kivyfilestests(App):
    def build(self):
        return Entry()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    kivyfilestests().run()
```

Name your file as kivyfilestests.kv

```
<Entry> # Seems to work with or without a colon :

    Label: #Rename to any of the following Label/Button/TextInput
        text: root.urs
```

Comment: By the way yourVariable = ObjectProperty("xxx") and root.yourVariable does the same thing as StringProperty("xxx") mentioned above. Don't ask me why.